# covariance matrix in the CAPM model

Tags: portfolio-optimization, capm, beta, covariance

I'm running a simulation for a 5 asset portfolio, calculating the optimal weights of each asset both with the statistical model (i.e. single index) and with the CAPM. my question is: how do you compute the covariance matrix in the CAPM? should I use the beta of each stock or the w% invested in each stock?

Comment: By "the w% invested in each stock" you mean the market weights in the Market Portfolio?

Comment: By "the beta of each stock" you mean you would use the equation $V= \sigma^2_M B B^T + \text{Diag} (E)$ to find the covariance matrix $V$ ?

Comment: w% are the market weights invested in each stock so that the sum of w% = total portfolio.

Comment: for the second part, it is actually the answer to my question, in the way that you are suggesting that covariance in the CAPM is computed through betas and not through weights as is in the Markovitz full-covariance matrix. am I right?

Comment: Your question(s) are confusing to me, with many complicated elements (simulation, single index model, optimal weights, Markowitz, what should I use). If the question is shortened to "what is the covariance matrix of stocks under the CAPM theory?" then the answer the textbooks give is the equation for V that I gave above. Look it up. To ask a more complicated question you need to explain your goal, the data available, why you need a covariance matrix, more clearly. (If the CAPM is true, then nobody needs a covariance matrix, they can just buy the market portfolio.)